# Force Firefox to Standards compliance mode

Tags: php, firefox, sugarcrm

I am using sugarCRM at my localhost.

For no apparent reason firefox is viewing the page in Quirks mode (the login page). This is completely messing up the page, here is a sample of the data shown:

> ��������Z�n7�-}v�fd4��q�Z�·8�ڱa�-�
>   f(�
>   5�rf��<�b���y�=��ftwRw�@"����m�<�2��^?}�
>   -��Ӌ�s���w|�#��Wo����U��'���a�n�{2��f0f1�E��~K���
>   fA\�$♞)�ioDU���]�U�;�$�`��krp@�XKE|I�p&k������C[rP��!��?�tH��9�j�p=

I thought this might be the server's fault (apache) but if I use Epiphany I can see the page perfectly. When I see the pages info, I see that the render mode is in quirks mode.

Is there any way to force it to use the Standards compliance mode?

I am on ubuntu 9.10 using Firefox 3.5 (I also tried 3.0.15, same thing happened) I disabled all the extension and I still got the same page. A friend tried viewing it with Chrome and the same thing happened :(

Comment: Could you point us to the page? Then one could make a more educated guess.

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't it be an encoding issue? E.g., your Apache sends

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Big5
```

but your HTML page is simply ASCII. Then you get gibberish as that. If you know your HTML encoding, try "View" -> "Character Encoding" in FF and switch back and forth a bit.

Alternatively, look at Apache's httpd.conf and search for the

```
AddDefaultCharset
```

setting.

Comment: Seconded. This doesn't look like a rendering mode issue.

Answer (score 2):

To get Firefox to render a page in standards-compliant mode, add a DOCTYPE to your HTML. For example, if you're using HTML (as opposed to XHTML), use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/DTD/strict.dtd">
```

You might find this Wikipedia link helpful - [triggering different rendering modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

Answer (score 2):

The screwed up data you posted suggests that the character encoding your document uses and the character encoding that Firefox thinks it uses does not match.

1. Pick a character encoding
2. Make sure you use it in your document
3. Make sure your Content-Type header specifies that encoding

http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/ is a useful guide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP 5.3? It may be the reason.
What is your Sugar version?

Comment: I am using php 5.2.11 and I have the latest sugarcrm ce

Comment: Please let me know the exact Sugar version